# T-SQL: Count and Group By Across Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following table:

```
Name | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
John   A      B      C
John   A      D      A
Bill   A      A      D
Bill   F      A      A
Steve  F      A      B
Steve  C      C      A
```

I want to know a total of how many As John, Bill, and Steve have...

e.g. John: 3, Bill: 4, Steve: 2

How could I do this using T-SQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select name, count(val) TotalAs
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  val
  for col in (col1, col2, col3)
) u
where val = 'A'
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ac5c/5)

Comment: +1 very elegant. Were I posting answers I would still be doing this the old fashioned way.

Comment: Yep, aggravation no longer worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [SQL Fiddle For below](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/377c4/2):

```
declare @table table (name varchar(10), c1 char(1), c2 char(1), c3 char(1))
insert into @table
SELECT 'John','A','B','C' UNION
SELECT 'John','A','D','A' UNION
SELECT 'Bill','A','A','D' UNION
SELECT 'Bill','F','A','A' UNION
SELECT 'Steve','F','A','B' UNION
SELECT 'Steve','C','C','A' 

; WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT name, 
       (SELECT Count(CASE WHEN val = 'A' Then 1 ELse Null end) 
        FROM (VALUES (c1),(c2),(c3)) AS value(val)) As ACOL
   from @table
)

SELECT Name, SUM(ACOL) ACount FROM CTE GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for SQL Server 2012?  It may be faster.

```
select name,sum(datalength(concat(col1,col2,col3))-
                datalength(replace(concat(col1,col2,col3),'A','')))
from yourtable
group by name;
```